# PHP pass record id to another page without showing it in the URL

Tags: php, html, get

I'd like to know if there is a way to pass a record id to another page without showing in the URL (using $_GET).
This is my code:

```html
    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>#</td>
          <td>Sigla</td>
          <td>Nome</td>
          <td>Bilancio</td>
          <td>Responsabile</td>
          <td>Azione</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <?php foreach ($rows as $row): ?>
        <tr>
          <td><?=$row['id']?></td>
          <td><?=$row['sigla']?></td>
          <td><?=$row['nome']?></td>
          <td><?=$row['bilancio']?></td>
          <td><?=$row['responsabile']?></td>
          <td class="actions">
            <a href="update.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="edit">
              <i class="fas fa-pen fa-xs"></i>                
            </a>
            <a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="trash">
              <i class="fas fa-trash fa-xs"></i>
            </a>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

As you can see for each record i create an `<href>` with the redirect to the "delete" or "update", so i will pass the id via $_GET.
Is there a way to not show the id in the URL?

Comment: remove the link and use a form. But anyone can still change the value of the id via the form. So maybe also do some more server-side checks

Comment: LOL. One visit from google bot and the database is empty

Comment: Use AJAX with a confirm too

Comment: Even if you use a form, you'd still have to pass the id in a hidden field, but anyone who cares to see the source of the page will see the id. I don't think there is a way of achieving this without having the id visible. If you have security concerns, you might want to think about authentication.

Comment: @mplungjan thank you for the advice, if you don't understand i'm a newbie in this field so sorry for the blasphemy but i'll keep in mind your advice

Comment: The id being visible in the URL is an absolute non-issue. The real issue is that any destructive operation must use POST, which means a form when using plain HTML. Further, if you don't want users deleting other users' data, you need to ensure that through permission checking server-side.

Comment: @deceze okay, so how can i do it? (keeping in mind that it is need a confirmation before the deleting process)

Comment: How can you do *what* exactly? The POST? The authentication? The permission checking?

Comment: You can use something like this https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/encryption. Encrypt your parameters that are present in url and pass them from backend to the frontend and then pass it from you user as a parameter and decrypt it. this use a key and others can't decrypt it.

Comment: i mean, should i insert it in a form? @deceze

Comment: @MohammadZareMoghadam thank you mohammad! I'll try it, this is another intelligent solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need AJAX or a form

Using a link to delete is VERY dangerous since once viist from a crawler and your database is corrupt

I suggest something like this

1. delegate the click to the container table
2. use data-attributes for the ID
3. Ajax using POST - I use `fetch` to do that here

```js
let fetchData = {
  method: 'POST'
}
const url = "delete.php";
document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains("trash") && confirm("Delete "+this.id+"?")) {
    e.preventDefault();
    fetchData["body"] = {
      "id": this.getAttribute("data-id")
    };
    fetch(url, fetchData)
      .then(function() {
        console.log("deleted");
      });
  }
})
```

```html
<a href="#" data-id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="trash">
  <i class="fas fa-trash fa-xs"></i>
</a>
```

Comment: [Not enough jQuery!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19492/476) Seriously, suggesting AJAX as the first thing is a bit overkill.

Comment: @deceze Where is the jQuery here? Seriously to not POST a single click instead of reloading the entire page for one click is poor UX and overkill if any

Comment: @mplungjan i've heard about it, so do you mean passing data between 2 pages using Jquery?

Comment: No. There is no jQuery here. I call your delete on click on the trash. In the .then, you can hide the row or whatever

Comment: The OP seems to be asking for ways to hide the real ID from the request. Sounds like OP wants to implement obscurity

Comment: @SimoneDeLuca What "other method" ?

Comment: you said "then no more is needed than an Ajax call", can you tell me how can i do it?

Comment: I just did. 'fetch' is Ajax

Answer (score 0):

The id being shown in the URL is an absolute non-issue. That doesn't make the delete operation any more secure or insecure. What you have are one, perhaps two, other issues:

- Any destructive operation must use POST requests. Normal links are free to be crawled by search engines, or preloaded by browsers. Which means, as soon as Google has crawled all your links, your database will be empty. That's why using POST is important, because every properly behaved HTTP client understands that POST is destructive.
- If you're asking this question because you're afraid users can simply manipulate the id shown in the URL and delete other records they're not supposed to delete, then your real issue isn't in where you pass the id, but that you have no permission checking on your server.

For starters, use a form to create POST requests:

```
<form action="delete.php?id=<?php echo htmlspecialchars(urlencode($row['id'])); ?>" 
      method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Delete">
</form>
```

(Also note the proper way to URL-encode and HTML-encode the value, since you're embedding it in a URL in the context of HTML.)

On the PHP side, you'd process this something like this:

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    // permission checking here
    // delete record here
}
```

Instead of transporting the ID as a query parameter, you could also make it a form field:

```
<form action="delete.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['id']); ?>">
    <input type="submit" value="Delete">
</form>
```

On the server you'd then take the value from `$_POST['id']` instead of `$_GET['id']`.

Note that this does not fundamentally change anything and is mostly a matter of taste.

You can customise that drab submit button in [various](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) [ways](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/image), or perhaps switch to more interactive Javascript; but those are all just ways to pretty up this basic operation.

Comment: Having a form per delete is poor UX. Waiting for the server to update to complete page with tons of HTML, is overkill when a simple post to the server using AJAX will suffice. If it is just a "don't show the ID in the URL because it is ugly" then no more is needed than an Ajax call

Comment: Yes, but that is about polishing the UX. I'm explaining the basics of destructive requests here first and foremost and try to address OPs primary question about showing the id in the URL. Also, OPs current UX is the same, and that doesn't appear to be a primary concern.

Comment: Well My answer got voted down for answering the question from the UX side, assuming the ID showing was more a symptom of using href to delete which I also commented on under the question

Comment: @mplungjan can you suggest mean example with the other method with the ajax to delete without reloading the page? i'd like to have both method available.

Comment: @deceze BTW, spam bots will try to submit your form, with more or less same result as the href in the original question. My suggestion is at least only running if someone confirms the delete

Comment: @mplungjan If your server allows unauthenticated requests to delete records, your issue is bigger than spam bots. Using a Javascript confirmation only "protects" you if nobody bothers to customise their bot to your site; once somebody does, you have the same issue.

Comment: @deceze I am referring to the random form bot submitters - we both realise that OP seems to need to fix more issues than just this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by something like this https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/encryption

At back-end you have to encrypt all your parameters like the following code:

```
$encryptedParameters = encrypt([
  'id' => 132,
  'something' => 'value',
  'another_key' => 'another_value',
]);
```

and then send this value to your html template.

At front-end if you want to do it by `GET` do something like this and your users can't see what are you sending to your back-end because it is encrypted:

```
<a href="delete.php?s=<?php echo $encryptedParameters; ?>"></a>
```

and if you want to do it by `POST` you can do it by `Ajax` or by generating a form and putting this value as a hidden input inside it. and then when user clicked on this link at back-end you have to decrypt it and use it's values like the following code:

```
$decryptedParameters = decrypt($_GET['s']);
$id = $decryptedParameters['id'];
$something = $decryptedParameters['something'];
$another_key = $decryptedParameters['another_key'];
```

Answer (score -1):

Convert the GET request to a Post using a hidden form submission, a preferred method is to encrypt the record id when submitting the data.

Comment: Why exactly is "encrypting the record id" a "preferred method"? And can you show a more concrete example of what a hidden form submission would look like?

Comment: It's not reliable to show the records ids to the public especially from a browser URL.

Comment: And why is that?

Comment: When listing the records in the data grid, use a form submission with POST request, make the delete link to have a button role.

Comment: And why is that? – deceze : to avoid SQL injection  from the people who understanding the actions behind, also for better lisability and proper display, to avoid knowing what exactly the id of each record that 's already saved in the database, data becomes unsecure - this method is preferred for some types of projects for more security.

Comment: SQL injection has absolutely ***nothing*** to do with this. I don't know what "lisability and proper display" means. Knowing the exact id *may* be a concern, yes. Usually it's irrelevant, but it *may* leak some meta information about your records which may be of interest to certain people. E.g., how many records you have in the database at all. Or simply crawling all records by incrementing their id. But that is not a problem per se and should only be mitigated if it *is* of concern for your particular case. And if it is, e.g. unpredictable UUIDs instead of ints are usually a good solution.

Comment: Right. It's about the fashion used.